# Pipeline-like operation using TChan

Tags: multithreading, haskell, stm

I want to implement a pipeline between two threads. I have thread A that take the data, process it, and send it to thread B. I have a MVar that check if the data is completely processed

However, I'm having an exception `*** Exception: thread blocked indefinitely in an STM transaction`

Why are my threads blocked? I though than when the first thread write on the channel, then when there is a data on the channel, the second one can read it

```
fstPipe :: (a -> b) -> TChan b -> MVar () -> [a] -> IO ()
fstPipe f chIn m xs = do
    ( mapM_(\x-> atomically $ writeTChan chIn $ f x) xs) >> putMVar m ()

pipelineDone channel mIn = do
    isDone <- fmap isJust $ tryTakeMVar mIn
    isEmpty <- atomically $ isEmptyTChan channel
    return $ isDone && isEmpty

lastPipe f chIn mIn = iter 
    where iter = do
        atomically $ fmap f $ readTChan chIn
        isDone <- pipelineDone chIn mIn
        unless isDone $ iter

pipeline = do
    chIn <- atomically newTChan
    m <- newEmptyMVar
    first <- async $ fstPipe reverse chIn m $ replicate 10 [1..500]
    last <- async $ lastPipe print chIn m
    wait first
    wait last
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems odd to me to be using STM *and* semaphores in the same code block... Why not do the entire thing in STM?

In particular, why not a `TChan (Maybe x)`, with `Nothing` indicating the end of the sequence?

Also, notice that your `fstPipe` likely just generates a bunch of unevaluated thunks and immediately chucks them into the `TChan`, without actually computing anything. You probably want a `seq` or similar in there to force some actual *work* to happen on that thread.

Comment: Thanks! So if I understand well, if I write "writeTchan chin $ seq $ f x" it will evaluate f x then add it to the channel?

Comment: If you do `writeTChan ch $! f x` (notice `$!` rather than `$`), that will force the result of `f` *to weak-head normal-form*. If you want to evaluate further than that... well, this is an entire other question. Search SO for previous answers. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I think there's a race condition:

- stop `fstPipe` just before the `putMVar`
- advance `lastPipe` to read everything, and then call `pipelineDone`
- `pipelineDone` returns `False` since `putMVar` was not yet done
- `lastPipe` will try to read from the channel
- `putMVar` executes, but it's too late

Now `lastPipe` is stuck reading on an empty channel.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in the logic of `pipelineDone`.  Currently, you have:

```
pipelineDone channel mIn = do
  isDone <- fmap isJust $ tryTakeMVar mIn
  isEmpty <- atomically $ isEmptyTChan channel
  return $ isDone && isEmpty
```

`tryTakeMVar` is going to take the contents of the MVar assuming there is something in there.  Assuming your producer finishes first, it is going to write `()` into the MVar.  Your consumer is then going to try and take the contents of it.  If it succeeds, then the MVar goes empty.  Any subsequent `tryTakeMVar` will always return `Nothing`, thus `isDone && isEmpty` will always return false and you will keep trying to read from the `TChan`.  Once the `TChan` goes empty, GHC can tell you that it has encountered a deadlock.

You should instead change your pipelineDone implementation to:

```
pipelineDone channel mIn = do
  stillRunning <- isEmptyMVar mIn
  isEmpty <- atomically $ isEmptyTChan channel
  return $ (not stillRunning) && isEmpty
```

This will instead simply poll the MVar, instead of actually emptying it.